# com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton "OutlinedButton" style in Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

I've used **MaterialButton** but my expected design not came. Below my xml code and style.

I've need white color of the background instead of the orange color, what I can do to achieve this. Please provide your suggestion.

[image]

```
// Material Design version I've used
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

**Color primary** means orange color.

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btnWatchVideo"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/watch_video"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:strokeColor="@color/colorBlack"
                app:strokeWidth="2dp" />


<style name="SliderThemeBlack" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

Manifest:
    <activity android:name="xxx" 
    android:theme="@style/SliderThemeBlack"  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `app:backgroundTint="@color/white"` to your MaterialButton

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I've used but same result coming. (Orange color only showing)

Comment: `SliderThemeBlack` where you used this?

Comment: I've used this on Manifest file of that Activity.

Comment: <activity
            android:name="xxx"
            android:theme="@style/SliderThemeBlack"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

Comment: there is no any issue in your `style` and `app:backgroundTint`. problem is somewhere else. try to find where is the problem

Comment: Yes you are saying correct this is working fine. In my code hard-code the backgroundtint value so previously not working.